# Glyphicons on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, glyphicons

I got a problem with Glyphicons when I open my project in Firefox (localhost).

Some icons appear and some not.

I saw in another thread that I should modify the `security.fileuri.strict` on `about:config` in firefox and I do that, but without success because still the same issue.

**Example HTML**

`<span style="font-size: 12px;" class="glyphicons search iconWitgats"></span>`

**CSS**

`.glyphicons.search:before { content: "\E028"; }`

When the page is rendered, appears a square in Firebug on content property in `.glyphicons.search:before`

This is a simple sample that what I saw in FireBug

`.glyphicons.old_man:before {
    content: "";
}
.glyphicons.woman:before {
    content: "";`
}

Answer (score 0):

look at this code :

```
.glyphicons.old_man:before {
```

this code says content is applied to element that have both `glyphicons` and `old_man` as class name but your span does not have old_man as class , add this class name to it too .

Comment: This was just a sample. What I want with this code, is what Firebug show me. Look the Woman and Look the OldMan. The Woman exist, but oldman is a square

Comment: hmm so if you are sure that glyph is included into your font file and typed correct number of that glyph in content , it is possible that browser cached a old version of your font file. i say this because i faced with this problem when i added new glyph into my font file. and after pressing control + f5 , i saw my problem resolved.